# How to send a SYN packet to a web server with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

So in order to try and hack into my own web server for security reasons, I would like to try and open many half-connection to dos my server. So how would I manually send an SYN packet to the server. I know that you can do this with the python library Scapy, but i would prefer to do this with javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you add the `node.js` tag so people who follow Node tag but not JavaScript tag will find your question? I assume you're working with Node since this isn't possible in browser-side JavaScript.

Comment: yes i will do that and yes i am working with node

Comment: I don't think there's anything lower level than https://nodejs.org/api/net.html (though of course you can install a plugin)

Comment: so will this tell me how to send a syn request

Comment: Well I wouldn’t say JS/NodeJS is a good language for that :/ C/C++/Python would be a better tool...